# Is there way to commitSync() in Spring Kafka on Consumer side?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

In our use case we want to synchronously commit as soon as the message is proceed by the consumer. From looking at the http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/ I don't see a way to do this with current version of API.

I do see there is `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, but still the underlying its `commitAsync()`. Is there a way of synchronously committing the transaction?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync() ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using property `setSyncCommits` on Kafka `ListenerContainerFactory`.

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
```